# Bundle page resources like images in single HTTP response

Tags: html, http, http-headers

For resources like CSS and JS, these things are **normally** separate resources (which each require separate a HTTP request/response to get).  But they **can be** inlined to reduce the number of separate resources.

I am wondering if the same sorta thing could apply to images.

- Maybe include the images in the header?
- Or inline in the actual HTML (in Base64 encoding or something)?

(1) Is this possible?  (2) Is this a good idea? (why or why not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reducing requests related to images, you can use CSS Sprites / Image Sprites which combines all the images in a single image (so only 1 request to server), which can then be shown as different elements using CSS

Refer [W3Schools guide](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) for more information

[Spritepad](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/) is a good tool to generate image sprites

Inline HTML for images using base64 can become bulky as it would be downloaded everytime the page is fetched instead of caching the image